# Does telegram api support inline keyboards?

Tags: telegram

I can see that telegram bot api supports inline keyboard, such as [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py). 
Does the inline keyboard functionality exist in telegram API as well? ie can a user pass an inline keyboard to a chat?